# how to pass the data received from webview onmessage function to reducer

Tags: react-native

Using onmessage function, i have recieved the data from webview, but how to store these data eg. cache value in reducer.

here iam storing recieved data in array and passing the array to **this.props.cmidata({ 'value': cmidataArray })**
**but iam getting error undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props)**

```
<WebView
        source={Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
        { uri: RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath + "/offlineplayer/index.html" } :
        { uri: 'file:///android_asset/offlineplayer/index.html' }
      }
          ref={(webView) => this.webView = webView}
          originWhitelist={["*"]}
         javaScriptEnabled={true}
         domStorageEnabled={true}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          useWebKit={true}
          onLoad={() => this.sendPostMessage()}
          onMessage={this.onMessage}
          allowFileAccess={true}
         />

 onMessage() {
    objcache = event.nativeEvent.data
     var cache = JSON.parse(objcache)

    //code to store the value in reducer
   var cmidataArray = []
  let cmidatavalues = {
    course_code: this.state.id,
    onlineCmidataJsonObjectList: cache
  }
  cmidataArray.push(cmidatavalues)

this.props.cmidata({ 'value': cmidataArray })

}
```

Comment: Try changing onMessage to an arrow function, `onMessage = () => {`. I am assuming you haven't explicitly bound your function.

Comment: @Dan Thank You so much, this was very helpful...